# How to know if a geocoded search is a city, village or town

Tags: geocoding, mapbox

I'm using the MapBox Geocoding API to allow users to search for cities, villages or towns. Now I need to know if the user's choice is exactly a city, a village or a town.
I'm currently using MapBox because it's free, do you think it's better to use GoogleMaps API, is it more complete?

I thought about a solution that consist on calculating the area of the place using the bbox informations, but it's the best way.

The criteria I'm going to use to distinguish cities and villages is based on the population and extensions.

Let me give you and example, if I use the following link to search for "Milan" for example, this is the outcome:

```
API LINK REQUEST:
https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${placeName}.json?limit=10&proximity=ip&types=${stringTypes}&fuzzyMatch=true&access_token=TOKEN_HERE;

  {
     "id":"place.11898823076804740",
     "type":"Feature",
     "place_type":[
        "place"
     ],
     "relevance":1,
     "properties":{
        "wikidata":"Q490"
     },
     "text":"Milano",
     "place_name":"Milano, Milan, Italy",
     "bbox":[
        9.041082,
        45.387103,
        9.277905,
        45.535973
     ],
     "center":[
        9.1905,
        45.4668
     ],
     "geometry":{
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[
           9.1905,
           45.4668
        ]
     },
     "context":[
        {
           "id":"region.5101199540804740",
           "short_code":"IT-MI",
           "wikidata":"Q15121",
           "text":"Milan"
        },
        {
           "id":"country.2840014219519910",
           "wikidata":"Q38",
           "short_code":"it",
           "text":"Italy"
        }
     ]
  }
```

Comment: You could use the Wikidata IDs to fetch more information, but it's a little involved e.g https://observablehq.com/@mbostock/hello-wikidata

Comment: That wikidata ID for "Milan" is for some old definition of Milan, which has no population data, but it leads me to https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q18288155 which has a population... I guess some local restructuring has been done...

Comment: Ok that's cool, I'll try but in this way i need to make at least tow API calls, Is possibile make only one, maybe using google api? Thank you